# Inconsistent phrasing in part of the FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed

Under the heading

> **I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?**

The [CodeReview FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) states (emphasis mine):

> Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer must be yes to all questions:
>
> - Does ***my*** question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, not a link to it)
> - Did ***I*** write that code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather then pseudo-code or example code?
> - To the best of ***your*** knowledge, does the code work?
> - Do ***you*** want feedback about any or all facets of the code?

**This inconsistent English phrasing needs to be corrected.**

- Either use the first person (*my, I*) **every time,**
- or use the second person (*your, you*) **every time.**

Code Review [has 4,789 visits every day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review), and many of these visitors will read the FAQ. At 608 days into public beta, this site should be as professional as possible, so inconsistencies like this *matter.*

Given the introductory sentence *"ask yourself the following questions..."*, the first option would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed. Thank you for the report.

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix! I think the tag `status-completed` may be appropriate now ;)